# How concat table's name in pl/sql?

Tags: oracle, plsql

code:

```
declare
    table_name varchar2(200) :='MY_TABLE_';
begin
    select * from table_name||'YYYY';
end;
```

I know  execute_immediate, is there another way to do this?

Comment: Simple answer is No, you can't do that without running dynamic sql, with execute immediate.

Comment: And you need to select into a variable (or open a cursor for the select).

Comment: @MT0 Yes, I need to.

Comment: use RENAME in dynamic SQL

Answer (score 1):

> Try this. It should give you some pointer. Let me know if this helps.

```
var p_lst refcursor;
DECLARE
  lv_tab_name VARCHAR2(100 CHAR):='emp';
BEGIN
  OPEN :p_lst FOR 'SELECT * FROM '||lv_tab_name;
END;

print p_lst;
```